# Creating a vehicle starting circuit

Tags: relay, 12v, button

My vehicle's ignition barrel has given up the ghost, and instead of replacing it, i want to go with a push to start system. I have already sourced a start button and only released after chucking the slip that it pulled to ground. Can you guys help me?

Relay 1:

- Pin 30: 12v From Battery with SW1 closed
- Pin 85: SW2 From Per 12v + LED(positive) on Button
- Pin 86: Goes to Relay 2 + Accessory 12v + LED(positive) on Button
- Pin 87: Goes to Ground

Relay 2:

- Pin 30: 12v From Relay 1 with SW1+SW2 Closed
- Pin 85: Needs 12v
- Pin 86: Goes to Starting Circuit
- Pin 87: Goes to Ground

Normally the ground of the STRT pin on Button (which is push to make) will supply the 12v to Pin 86 on Relay 2 to send 12v to the starting circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faZh1k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "*... and only released after chucking the slip that it pulled to ground.*" Translation, please (and fix the title too)? Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar that you can save an editable schematic in-line. No need for screengrabs. You need to explain how your circuit is supposed to work. It's not clear from the schematic.

Comment: Relay 2 will short-circuit 12 V to ground when it is energised. This might never happen though because you have 12 V on the left side of the coil and on the right side too.

Comment: Even if you discarded the sales receipt and can't return the switch that you have, it might still make sense to go back and get the correct switch rather than trying to make this one work, which will require another relay. Especially given that your schematic shows a very tenuous grasp of how electronics works ...

Comment: My apologies, has been a long day at work. Fixed the picture

Comment: (1) The text references pin numbers that aren't marked on the schematic. (2) You haven't explained "*and only released after chucking the slip that it pulled to ground.*" (3) What is SW2 supposed to do? (4) Is RLY2 the starter solenoid or does its contact energise the starter solenoid? (5) If you post embed the editable schematic in your question we can copy it into our answers and fix it.

Comment: 1. My apologies, need a membership to CircuitLab hence screenshot. 2. Item is non returnable (other one's did not have LED's) 3. SW1 is a secret switch located in the car to power the whole circuit. SW2 is cycle close the relay circuit sending 12v to RLY2 and Accessories. 4. RLY2 energises the starter solenoid. 5. How does one embed schematic without Membership?

Comment: Fixed Schematic on Edit

Comment: OK, it's getting better. I think you mean "realized" and not "released" and "chucking" means "threw away"? So the whole question is really how to energise RLY2 with the start button that has one contact connected to ground?

Comment: 100% Transistor. I've been sitting with this the whole weekend, came across the forum and gave it a shot in the dark

Comment: why do you think that the switch has one contact connected to ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEw2xc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Modified circuit. Add in the red and green wires. (LEDs removed as it is not clear how these are wired internally.)*

This circuit requires that P85 and P87 are not internally connected to ground. (This can be checked with a continuity tester when the wires are disconnected.)